# Extract a string from a searched column index on the row below?

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to make a simple disk usage shell script (in dash), but unsure how to parse this string because I'm not familiar with AWK's syntax.

I use this command: `df -P -BG /`, and, for example, it gives me an output like this:

```
Filesystem                  xxxxxxxxxx-blocks  Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/mapper/xxx_crypt                    500G  200G      100G      xx% /
```

I want to extract the column below under "Used" (and eventually "Available"), but not sure how I should do it. I know AWK has a search command like this: `awk '/Used/ {print}'`

But I am not sure how to get the row underneath it. Any tips? It's pretty important to me that it works as a pipe on one line, such as `df -P -BG / | awk '...'` since I'm storing it in a shell variable, but it's not strictly necessary, I suppose, since multi-line AWK can be used instead.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the _exact_ output you expect from the example input. Also tell us what operating system you are using which will indicate what implementations of `awk` and `df` you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for FPAT, FIELDWIDTHS, \s, \S, and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FPAT="\\S+|\\s+"; OFS="\t" }
NR == 1 {
    sub(/Mounted on/,"Mounted_on")
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i+=2 ) {
        tags[++numTags] = $i
        wids = wids " " length($i $(i+1))
    }
    FIELDWIDTHS = wids
    $0 = $0
}
{
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        f[tags[i]] = gensub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"","g",$i)
    }
    print f["Filesystem"], f["Available"], f["Used"]
}
```

```
$ cat file | awk -f tst.awk | column -s $'\t' -t
Filesystem             Available  Used
/dev/mapper/xxx_crypt  100G       200G
```

Replace `cat file` with `df -P -BG /` which I don't have. I'm just piping to `column` to make the columns line up, it's not necessary.

With that approach you can print, compare, reorder, do arithmetic on, etc. the values of whatever columns you like by their name. The only one I had to massage in the code was "Mounted on" to change the space to an underscore.

Here's a version that'll work in any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR == 1 {
    sub(/Mounted on/,"Mounted_on")
    while ( match(substr($0,totWid+1),/[^ \t]+[ \t]*/) ) {
        tag = substr($0,totWid+1,RLENGTH)
        sub(/[ \t]+$/,"",tag)
        tags[++numTags] = tag
        begs[numTags] = totWid + 1
        wids[numTags] = RLENGTH
        totWid += RLENGTH
    }
}
{
    for ( i=1; i<=numTags; i++ ) {
        val = substr($0,begs[i],wids[i])
        gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"",val)
        f[tags[i]] = val
    }
    print f["Filesystem"], f["Available"], f["Used"]
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s $'\t' -t
Filesystem             Available  Used
/dev/mapper/xxx_crypt  100G       200G
```

Comment: I am glad there are some AWK wizards around here, because I am trill trying to learn more of the syntax myself. This answer would work specifically with `gawk`, but I am using `mawk` on this system, which doesn't have `gensub()`, so this won't work for me. This is fantastic though!

Comment: @mrjpaxton I added a version that'll work in any awk.

Comment: Oh, great! Hey, this seems to work pretty well, and it in fact did answer the question, even though I am using a line with less code for the time being, I will mark yours as the accepted answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If your `df` implementation supports it, you can use `--output` instead of parsing. From `man df` on my Arch Linux:

```
--output[=FIELD_LIST]
  use the output format defined by FIELD_LIST, or print all fields if
  FIELD_LIST is omitted.

[...]

FIELD_LIST is a comma-separated list of columns to be included.  
Valid field names  are:  'source',  'fstype',  'itotal',  'iused',
'iavail',  'ipcent', 'size', 'used', 'avail', 'pcent', 
'file' and 'target' (see info page).
```

So, in your case, you would just do:

```
$ df  -BG --output="used" /
 Used
  200G
```

---

If you really need to parse it, I wouldn't bother with the pattern matching at all. You control the input, it won't change, so you can just print the 3rd field (output from my system):

```
$ df -P -BG / | awk '{print $3}'
Used
44G
```

If you really really need to have it work even if the field order changes, so you need to find what field contains the string `Used`, you could do something complicated like this:

```
$ df -P -BG / | 
   awk '{ if(NR==1){for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ if($i ~ /Used/){want=i}}} print $want}'
Used
44G
```

Comment: `df --output` does not work with `df -P`, which is for POSIX compatibility. But I guess you have a point in that `df` output won't likely change order, but it's not impossible--it could happen. Thanks for your brisk answer!

Comment: @mrjpaxton why would you care for POSIX compatibility if all you want is to get a specific field? See `info df` for what that option affects. As for the order of the fields, that is part of the POSIX specs for df, so you can be pretty sure it won't change. At any rate, the order is no more likely to change than the name of the `Used` field. Why would you treat one as more reliable than the other? If you think the order can change, then the title can also, so you shouldn't use `df` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $target = "Used"; 
            my @table = lines.map: *.split(/ \h+ /).List; 
            my $col = @table.head.grep(/ $target /, :k).cache; 
            .put for @table.map: *.[ $col.flat ];'   file
```

Above is an answer written in Raku, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. Briefly, a `$`-sigiled scalar is declared and assigned the string "Used". Then `lines` are read-in, each `map`ped into and `split` on `\h` horizontal whitespace. Normally such a return would be held in a lightweight data structure known as a `Seq` in Raku, but here we coerce to `List` and save data in the `@table` array.

Now for the correct column. We take `@table.head` which gives us the original header row (i.e. line) of the table. We `grep` through these elements to find a match to `$target`, and we take the `:k` keys, i.e. column index number(s), storing them in `$col`. Finally, we out`put` the `@a.table` data, only returning the `$col` desired columns.

Sample Input:

```
Filesystem                  xxxxxxxxxx-blocks  Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/mapper/xxx_crypt                    500G  200G      100G      xx% /
```

Sample Output:

```
Used
200G
```

The OP expressed a desire to have a script that accepts shell variables. Raku has a special associative array `%*ENV` which can be used to access shell variables. So below takes the shell variable `colName` from the  environment (i.e. the shell):

```
~$ env colName="Used" raku -e 'my $target = %*ENV<colName>;   \
                      my @table = lines.map: *.split(/ \h+ /).List;     \
                      my $col = @table.head.grep(/$target/, :k).cache;  \
                      .put for @table.map: *.[ $col.flat ];'   file
Used
200G
```

You can similarly return two columns, etc., with only slight adjustment as below:

```
~$ env colNames="Used Available" raku -e '   \
                      my @target = %*ENV<colNames>.split(/ \h+ /).List;  \
                      my @table = lines.map: *.split(/ \h+ /).List;      \
                      my @col = @table.head.grep(/@target/, :k);         \
                      .put for @table.map: *.[ @col.flat ];'   file
Used Available
200G 100G
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/grep
https://raku.org